# Analytical badge

Tags: support, badges

I was looking at the badges and noticed that `Analytical`. So I read all the FAQ sections, but so far I havent gotten it. Am I missing something? Is there more to read, then just the qeustions listed on the FAQ page?

Comment: Try clicking every link therein.

Comment: Thats what I did. I only didn't click the links in the gray area at the bottom.

Comment: I read those questions, but I'm sure that I did all which was required, except the waiting for a few hours bit. So maybe it will be awarded later.

Comment: The FAQ section has been overhauled (replaced by the Help Center), I suspect that the badge may be broken at the moment. I **strongly** suspect that the linked question is now obsolete.

Comment: Well, I accidently got a differnet badge instead `Informed`. LOL

Comment: @Mat oops, saw your comment only after voting to close as the other one. :/

Comment: Thanks I haven't read that, as the title is not suggestive for my problem. To bad I wont get it now. :p

Comment: @Mat Thanks, that goes for me too, had no idea.

Answer (score 1):

`As of June 2013, this badge is no longer awarded due to the FAQ changed to Help Center all    across the network`

Comment: Dang! So I _**just**_ missed it?! :( all that time reading...poof :(